# Variable not loading in global environment after running Knitr Markdown script

Tags: r

After running a script in R with Knitr Markdown which contains this line:

x <- 3

Variabele x is not loaded into my Global environment.

Is there a method to overcome this?
Or can I find the value of x in another environment?

This because I want to do some calculations with the variables after running my script.

Thank you!

Comment: I think knitr runs in its own process, or at least with its own evaluation environment. You'll probably have to `save` the data in your script and then `load` it afterwards.